# How to pass a python lambda to win API function "LPVOID" param field exported from ctypes?

Tags: python, windows, winapi, ctypes

There's some parameter field in WinAPI function like the following one:

```
BOOL WINAPI EnumWindows(
  _In_  WNDENUMPROC lpEnumFunc,
  _In_  LPARAM lParam
);
```

The `"LPARAM lParam"` is for pass value to the EnumFunc callback.
Now I want used python `ctypes` module to call it and pass a "python `lambda` function" to that callback.

How can I do that?

Comment: It's usually simplest to use closures in these scenarios

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't quiet understand what you mean. I think my question can possibly be simplify to how to pass a python object to LPVOID and convert LPVOID to python object back in the WINFUNCTYPE style python funciton.

Comment: But you don't need to do that because the function that you pass as `lpStartAddress` has context and can contain whatever information you need. That's always the easiest way to do this. `lpParameter` is useful from unmanaged code where closures are often not available.

Comment: If you insist on using `lpParameter`, define the fourth parameter as `ctypes.py_object` in `CreateThread.argtypes`. You must keep a reference to the Python object while the thread is created; this protects against race conditions in which the object gets deallocated before the reference count is incremented in the new thread. In other words, don't use an anonymous `lambda` directly in the argument list. First assign the function to a local variable. Distasteful, right? Then use a closure or bound method instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do this. The Python interpreter probably isn't designed to be called from threads it hasn't created itself. To create a thread use Python's own built in support for threads (eg. `thread.start_new_thread` or `threading.Thread`). There's no reason to use ctypes and the Windows API directly here.

Comment: Yes, you are probably right. Actually, the example in my post is just a similar situation for simplify the real problem. The win function I really dealing with is "EnumWindows" and its second parameter " _In_  LPARAM lParam". Sorry for my poor example for explain the problem.

Comment: @inker You should update your question accordingly. Changing it to the real function and parameter you want to use isn't going to make the question any more complicated.

Comment: No, ctypes callbacks call [`PyGILState_Ensure`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html#c.PyGILState_Ensure). Native code can call back into Python using a new thread.

Comment: Python's `thread.start_new_thread` increments the reference count on the target function and arguments and doesn't decrement them until after the thread exits. OTOH, as I mentioned in the comments, with this  `CreateThread` example there's a brief window when the `py_object` argument can get deallocated in the calling thread, so the caller has to manually ensure the argument is kept alive until the reference count is incremented in the new thread.

Comment: @eryksun It's all moot anyways, as `CreateThread` is a red-herring. I'll delete or replace my answer once @inker updates his post to ask his real question.

Comment: [`EnumWindows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is much more pedestrian, since the callback is called on the same thread and the overall call doesn't return until it's finished enumerating the top-level windows.